# Get possible solution with DPLL algorithm

Tags: logic, algorithms, propositional-calculus

I was implementing the following DPLL algorithm in Prolog:

[DPLL implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY59d.png)

The implementation tells me if there is a solution for the given CNF, but is it also possible with DPLL algorithm to get one or all possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to keep track of how you got to the empty clause set.

In fact, in Prolog this is straightforward: add a list of literals as an argument to the function. When you make the first call, use an empty list, and then add $L$ to this list of literals whenever $\{ L \} \in F$ applies.

So, roughly, create a function DP(F,Ls) with:

DPLL([],[]).

DPLL(F,_):- element([],F), fail.

DPLL(F',[L|Ls]):- element([L],F),reduce(F,L,F').

DPLL([[L]|F],[L|Ls]):- element(C,F), element(L,F).

DPLL([[L']|F],[L'|Ls]):- element(C,F), element(L,F),complement(L,L').

(note that this is very inefficient, as it ends up splitting on every literal and complement that occur in any of the clauses ... so, for example, if some literal $A$ occurs multiple times in the clauses, then it will split on $A$ that many times, whereas obviously once should suffice)

Comment: Thanks, is the element I track the one which is the only element of one of the disjunktions (äquivalent to ```({Lit} ∈ F``` in the linked algorithm)?

Comment: @TmCrafz Yes, exactly!  And I assume you already wrote something akin to the 'reduce' function, right?

Comment: Yes, I have a function which deletes the positive elements from the disjunctions and remove the clauses which are always false

Comment: @TmCrafz Cool!  Yes, that process is typically referred as 'reducing the clause set with regard to some literal'. So is your code working?

Comment: My code is workig, all my tests pass. I'm currently changing my algorithm in Prolog so it's able to handle Prolog Variable instead of only Literals. Then I can unify with true/false values and get a solution